# PGLOADER migrating from MariaDB to PostGRE hangs error "table or database name 'untitled folder'"

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgloader

I seems that pgloader is not migrating my database. it hangs after the connection
after waiting a long time I `ctl + c` and it brings error below and no return to shell

```
An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
   Interactive interrupt at #x1A632A310.

What I am doing here?

Interactive interrupt at #x1A632A310.
```

dockers logs mariadb returns
`2023-07-20 14:11:50 362 [ERROR] Invalid (old?) table or database name 'untitled folder'`

docker logs postgre returns
`2023-07-20 14:10:14.838 UTC [28] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 677 buffers (4.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=71.948 s, sync=0.070 s, total=72.795 s; sync files=177, longest=0.012 s, average=0.001 s; distance=5462 kB, estimate=5462 kB`

```
pgloader version "3.6.9"
compiled with SBCL 2.3.4
```

`pgloader mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1/mr_dev postgresql://app:pass@127.0.0.1/mr_dev`

then prompt is stuck there

```
2023-07-20T10:08:37.009968-04:00 LOG pgloader version "3.6.9"
2023-07-20T10:08:37.017594-04:00 LOG Data errors in '/private/tmp/pgloader/'
2023-07-20T10:08:37.166152-04:00 LOG Migrating from #<MYSQL-CONNECTION mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/mr_dev {700BDE2483}>
2023-07-20T10:08:37.166316-04:00 LOG Migrating into #<PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://app@127.0.0.1:5432/mr_dev {700BF9B623}>
```